# Spring boot HATEOAS integration issue

Tags: java, spring-boot, hateoas

I have included `hateoas` dependency in my `spring boot` project but I am unable to run the project because of few exceptions that are being shown. I have tried cleaning the workspace, `mvn clean install` and also restarting the application but it's not working. Is there something I am missing here?

**pom.xml**

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.rest.webservices</groupId>
    <artifactId>restful-web-services</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>restful-web-services</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
            <version>0.15.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

**Exception**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.data.web.config.HateoasAwareSpringDataWebConfiguration] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@73d16e93]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:481) ~[spring-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:358) ~[spring-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:414) ~[spring-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.lambda$getTypeForFactoryMethod$2(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:743) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1660) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:742) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:681) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:649) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1605) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:523) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:494) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:616) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:608) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1242) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromMappedException(SpringApplication.java:869) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromException(SpringApplication.java:857) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleExitCode(SpringApplication.java:844) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:795) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:325) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at com.rest.webservices.restfulwebservices.RestfulWebServicesApplication.main(RestfulWebServicesApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/hateoas/server/mvc/UriComponentsContributor
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:463) ~[spring-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.hateoas.server.mvc.UriComponentsContributor
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    ... 42 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using `2.2.6.RELEASE` try using the latest version of hateoas `1.0.4.RELEASE` as suggested by Amir. 
Just note by doing so you will have to change some imports as the name of some Classes have been changed and moved. See here https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current/reference/html/ for example

> import static org.springframework.hateoas.mvc.ControllerLinkBuilder.*;

should be replaced by

> import static org.springframework.hateoas.server.mvc.WebMvcLinkBuilder.*;

`Resource` is now `EntityModel`. And so on ...

I hope this help

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the spring boot starter, maybe this will resolve your issue

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Amir, I had tried doing that but if I have only this dependency then I am unable use classes like `Resource`, `ControllerLinkBuilder`. The `hateoas` jar is not getting added to the application in the above case.

Comment: since you are using version `0.15.0.REALEASE` maybe this is version error. What spring boot-version are you using?

Comment: Ah I See you are using `2.2.6.RELEASE` maybe try with latest hateoas version `1.0.4.RELEASE`

Comment: Changing the version isn't helping either. Same issue with unable to find the classes I mentioned in the comments.

Comment: I tried reproducing your error but couldnt. please try creating a new project with spring initializr, adding hateoas there and just plugging your existing stuff in there. Maybe this will help

Answer (score 0):

**Wrong JRE**
I was using Eclipse (newbie) and was using the bundled JRE 15.  Once I switched to a 1.8 version I got a little farther.

See

- *Window | Preferences | Java | Compiler | JDK Compliance | Compiler compliance level*
- *Window | Preferences | Java | Installed JREs*

Answer (score 0):

try with oracle jdk 1.8 and clean up the project

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30412013)